# Source for information about Australia and U.S. real estate market rent-to-price ratios?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, online-data-source, australia, rent

Would like to make a comparison between the two markets, in particular during the global financial crisis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Economist aggregates data from financial lenders around the world.  [This article](http://www.economist.com/node/15911113) is their most recent analysis, but they also have a data site where you can play around and view [house-price data over time](http://www.economist.com/node/14438245?story_id=14438245).

[image]

Comment: Be careful with national comparisons. Many areas of the United States have barely been hit by the bubble, because there wasn't one in those areas.

Comment: Yip, which is why the US has two indexes.  The Federal Housing Finance Agency (FHFA) which is largely considered bunk, and the Case-Shiller index, which is considered significantly more accurate.